# Mix Hibernate strategy of inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(appliesTo = "A", indexes = {@Index(name = "a_uuid_idx", columnNames = {"uuid"})})
  public class A {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EntityID")
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   private Integer id;
}

  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("local.stored")
  public class B extends A {
   private String name;
}
```

And data from B successfully persists in table A.

```
   @Entity
   @DiscriminatorValue("second.stored")
   public class C extends B {
   private String lastname;
}
```

I expected, data from C to be persisted to table A (so, 3 etitties in one table). But it does not, despite the fact that DiscriminatorValue is used.
I tried also to aplly to class B annotation @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) in the hope that separate table for C will be created (so, 2 tables: 1 - for A/B  and 2 - for C). But without success.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not persist in table `A`, you only have one table for all 3 entities right? So `C` is not stored at all?

Comment: I am trying to find any variant of persisting C.  1. One table for all 3 entities.   2.  One table for A and B,   and second table for C